# Adapting path/directory to different users in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file saved on a share point. I would like that every users who has access to the file can run the python code automatically. The code looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\username\file path')
```

I would like to replace the username with the names of the user. So for example Martin would have

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Martin\file path')
```

So far I got:

```
user = easygui.enterbox('Please insert your username')

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\{user}\file path')
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df = pd.read_excel(fr'C:\Users\{user}\file path')
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [pathlib.Path.home()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home):

```py
from pathlib import Path

excel_path = Path.home() / "path" / "filename.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(str(excel_path))
```